# Which tense should I use: "My teacher was…" or "is"?

Tags: tense, past-simple

If someone has graduated and is talking about his teacher in high school, is the tense used correctly in the following sentence:

> My English teacher **is** a very nice person; he not only **taught** us English but also taught us how to grow into an upright, kind person. (He is still alive)

Also, can I still refer to him as "my teacher"？

Comment: …taught **us** how to grow into upright, kind **people/citizens**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My English teacher is a very nice person; he not only taught us English but also taught us how to grow into an upright, kind person. (He is still alive)

As he is no longer your teacher, we should use **former English teacher**.

We use **is** if he is still nice, and **was** otherwise.

The teaching is past, and hence **taught** is correct.

For a person no longer alive, we use **was** for point 2.

Comment: Note that using "is" suggests that you still have contact with him, because you know that he is still nice and would not know if you hadn't seen him since high school.

Comment: @YonKuma So if the speaker and his former teacher haven't been in touch for a long time,  even if he knows the teacher is alive, he can still use the word "was"？

Comment: @ForOU Yes. Although the teacher is not dead, all your interactions with them were in the past, so it makes sense to use the past tense when describing them at the time you knew them.